# Mirror modifier doesn't mirror correctly

Tags: modifiers, sculpting, mirror

I am trying to create the head of my character but noticed that a part of face is not symmetrical as expected.

Am I doing something wrong? not sure at what point this happened. Thank you for your time.

LE: Right side is what I'm creating. Left side is mirrored.

[image]

Comment: Do you have any other modifiers in the stack? If so, change the order of them to see if it changes anything about this behavior.

Comment: I did not had any other modifiers in place. Fixed it by deleting the faces and recreate them. Not sure what went wrong.